# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number error

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to save data in my Database but there is **TypeError** in my code. 
The actual error is:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'

So please help me to solve this issue.
The following is my code on Views.py:

```
    card = Cards_detail(request.POST)
    card.user_id = int((request.user.id))
    card.card_no = int(request.POST['card-number'])
    card.expiray_month = request.POST['expiry-month']
    card.expiray_year = request.POST['expiry-year']
    card.card_type = 'Visa'  #temp value change this value as per api
    #card.bank_id = 1         # temp value change this value as per api
    card.save()    # Saving Card Details
```

Comment: The actual error is :-TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'

Comment: please try printing request.POST['card-number'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line :

```
 card = Cards_detail(request.POST)
```

You can not use model **Cards_detail** with **request.POST** untill you are using a model from for that.
You need to use **objects.create** :

```
if request.POST: 
    card_no = int(request.POST.get('card-number')) 
    expiray_month = request.POST['expiry-month'] 
    expiray_year = request.POST['expiry-year'] 
    card_type = 'Visa'

    card = Cards_deatil.objects.create(user = request.user,card_no = card_no,expiray_month = expiray_month,expiray_year = expiray_year,card_type = 'Visa') 
    card.save()

    return HttpResponse('Done')
```

Comment: I had done like this but its not working still gave me that same error.I am confusion where should be error in user_id or card_no??

Comment: @AmazeLife show us the whole traceback. Please print total traceback of the error in the question. Then I will be able to help you in better way.

Comment: @AmazeLife And please show me the whole view, not just these 5 lines. Please paste your total code in the question.

Comment: File "D:\Python\Cashwalapp\cashwalappsecondary\Cwallet\views.py", line 54, in addmoney
    card.save()    # Saving Card Details

Comment: File "D:\Python\Cashwalapp\ENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 946, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)

Comment: card = Cards_detail(request.POST)card.user = request.user
        card.card_no = int(request.POST.get('card-number'))
        card.expiray_month = request.POST['expiry-month']
        card.expiray_year = request.POST['expiry-year']
        card.card_type = 'Visa'  #temp value change this value as per api
        #card.bank_id = 1         # temp value change this value as per api
        card.save()    # Saving Card Details
        print(request.POST.get('wallet_bal'))
        print(request.POST.get('old_bal'))
        return HttpResponse('Done')

Comment: @AmazeLife Please post the whole view from def get_prep_value(request).  The code before **card = Cards_detail(request.POST)** and the **Cards_detail** form code and the model of the form **Cards_detail** .

Comment: model.py :- class Cards_detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    card_no = models.BigIntegerField()
    expiray_month = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    expiray_year = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    card_type = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    bank_id = models.ForeignKey(Bank,null=True, blank=True)

Comment: before card = Cards_deatil(request.post)   user = request.user
    print(user)
    wallet = get_object_or_404(Wallet, user=request.user)

    if request.POST:

Comment: print(request.POST.get('wallet_bal'))
        print(request.POST.get('old_bal'))
        newbal = request.POST.get('wallet_bal')
        oldbal = request.POST.get('old_bal')
        updatebal = float(newbal) + float(oldbal)
        wallet.balance = updatebal
        wallet.updated_on = datetime.now()
        wallet.save() # Updatae Wallet balance

    return HttpResponse('Done')

Comment: @AmazeLife are you using any model form to save values in **Cards_detail** model??

Comment: actually no without using model form i am saving values

Comment: Then your method is altogehter wrong. You cant do that. Without model forms you can not save values inside db Like this. I am updating my answer. Please check.

Comment: okk actually i am very new to Django So will u help me more for this for CURD Opeartion process

Comment: where should I find this answer??Sorry but i didn't get this

Comment: if request.POST: 
    card = Cards_deatil.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)
    card.card_no = int(request.POST.get('card-number')) 
    card.expiray_month = request.POST['expiry-month'] 
    card.expiray_year = request.POST['expiry-year'] 
    card_type = 'Visa'

    card = Cards_deatil.objects.create(user = request.user,card_no = card_no,expiray_month = expiray_month,expiray_year = expiray_year,card_type = 'Visa') 
    card.save()

Comment: in above code : there is error as :- null value in column "card_no" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, null, , , , null, 17).

Comment: still giving same error :- null value in column "card_no" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (10, null, , , , null, 17).

Comment: if i print card_number value above this line  card = Cards_deatil.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user) then  it is printed

Comment: thank u so much for your valuable help.there is one more there is bank_id field which is foreign key of bank table so how to insert that filed in database